# Need specific VirtualBox version that can't run on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

I have a Windows XP (yes) VM on a Windows 7 Pro 64b using Oracle VB Version 5.0.32 r112930 - works like a charm for years.

My problem is that this VM works **only** in VB Version 5.0.32 version.
With ALL other tested versions, there's a video corruption and the top screen is populated of red/black rectangles - then BSOD or crash.

I tried to update video drivers and many things, it's an ULTRA long process. Couldn't make it behave better.

So my problem is: I'm stuck with a Windows 7 because Version 5.0.32 doesn't want to run on Windows 10 :-(

[This message, picture taken from another post, in EN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjlBz.png)

[On my system, in FR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbS2z.png)

Windows 10 (64b) 21H2 and 22H2, same result, fresh system install, tried:

- run in admin mode (and am admin), tried compatibility W7 and W8 (same result)
- activated Developper mode
- installed Hyper V, then removed it
- disabled memory integrity setting
- disabled defend and **all** security features, no A/V installed
- tried tens of VirtualBoxes versions I could install, they work well, but my VM crashes.

Is there something I could do, try?
Like maybe tricking this specific VB install so it accepts to run on Windows 10?

I read maybe a hundred of SuperUser pages install/run VirtualBox problems, couldn't find.

*PS: Very first question, sorry.
I read you people for years; MANY thanks for all what you did, it helped me a lot along my life.*

Edit: as it wasn't maybe clear enough, this Windows XP VM is a system working for 20 years (was on a PC before) and there's no way I can reinstall it from scratch, otherwise it'd be far less a problem.

Comment: Off the top of my head, would compatibility mode work?

Comment: I have Windows XP running in VMware Workstation V17 on a Windows 11 Host. No issues.   (A) Can you build a new XP machine in VBOX running on Windows 10?  (B) Can you try VMware Workstation (trial available) to see if that works?

Comment: In the post: tried compatibility W7 and W8 :-(
VMware didn't try their recent one since the very old Workstation which was free :-)
Problem also is I need this VM as is, can't reinstall everything. Not sure VMWare would import it?

Comment: Try this article for importing the VBOX machine to VMware.    https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2053864

Comment: Finally got it to *kind of* work! Had to set up disk as SCSI instead of SATA. When booting, zillions of new peripherals are detected. I'll try to make this VM work tomorrow. Maybe VMware Pro would have helped, more options. But 200$ is heavy. Anyway if I can make it work, then it'll be huge! Otherwise back to VirtualBox. Will let you know.

Comment: If you get this to work, please do [write an answer](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) to explain the details, then [accept](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer. This will make it helpful for others facing similar situation, and ensures the question won't pop up as "Unanswered" in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Windows XP running in VMware Workstation V17 on a Windows 11 Host. No issues.

(A) Can you build a new XP machine in VBOX running on Windows 10?

(B) Can you try VMware Workstation (trial available) as that should work.  Does for me.

Use this article for importing the VBOX machine to VMware.

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2053864

Comment: Thank you, but see my "Edit:" I really can't rebuild this machine.

Answer (score 1):

It (finally) worked on VMware 17 Workstation Player on Windows 10 22H2

*Thanks to @John - I tried everything except using VMware!*

From Windows 7 64 Pro, VirtualBox 5.0.32, found out you've to export as ova 1.0 (and not 2.0).

Also, SATA drives has to be imported as SCSI (SATA host too recent probably), otherwise BSOD.

Had some drives troubles, so I exported only the machine with no drive.
Then imported the drives manually (exported as vdmk).

**WARNING** at least in my case and for this VB 5.0.32, as there were snapshots in this VM, when I exported the drives as vmdk their content was the one of the **first** snapshot. I realized that the most recent data was from 2017!

As a solution I'd recommend the safe use of making a Clone of the VM while selecting "Current state".
But you could also delete all the snapshots...

Finally first VM boot, installed components and drivers missing.
Second boot, installed VMware add-ons.

*Frankly I'd have preferred a solution with VirtualBox, which has tons of options and features, and is free.
But of course, I'll keep this one, it works very well and doesn't crash the VM.*

Comment: I posted an answer and I trust you will acknowledge it.  Thanks,